# Sending legacy JavaBeans over HTTP

Tags: java, xml, json, rest, jaxb

We have components of a legacy system running in an application that contains an embedded Jetty HTTP server.  This legacy system has several JavaBeans (DTOs) that contain the information needed by our HTTP clients.  These beans don't have any annotations for JSON/XML serialization, and we don't want to make any modifications to the legacy system code.  We also don't want any dependencies on our clients to the old legacy system or its JavaBeans.

Finally, these beans have lots of complicated references to each other, and collections of each other.  The object graph of some beans have loops and non-trivial inheritance, so a simple serialization to JSON or XML blows up with loop stack overflow errors.

I'm looking for suggestions on a good way to do this.

One idea is to describe all these beans in XSD, and use that to generate new classes with the required JAXB annotations for serializing to JSON/XML.  We would manually assemble an object structure with these new beans from an instance of an object structure from the legacy system, then be able to send it over HTTP to clients with only a dependency on our new classes.  But this seems like a LOT of work.

Another idea is to subclass each of the legacy beans to add the needed XML/JSON JAXB annotations.  This might be easier than writing the XSD??  But we'd still need to assemble the new object graph of a bean instance from the object graph of the legacy beans.  And it would have a runtime dependency on the client to the legacy JavaBeans.

I've googled some on automatically generating XSD from existing Java classes.  Looks like there are some tools for that, but it would require us to modify the XSD so when the new classes are generated it would have the required annotations.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAXB does not require annotations. It can be configured externally.

Consider: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html

Also, I've found for many cases, the default (i.e. no annotations) work pretty well. So, you will likely not have a large burden to boot strap you code.

If you have a common "root" object that you're using, a single XmlRootElement starts the entire engine going, and even that isn't completely required.

You'll need to be careful of cyclic graphs in the your beans, but these can be managed as well with JAXB.

Comment: The JAXB (JSR-222) spec itself doesn't cover external metadata.  We offer an external mapping document in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) described by the link in your answer.  The JAXB reference implementation offers this ability using Annox:  http://confluence.highsource.org/display/ANX/JAXB+User+Guide

Comment: Thanks for the info.  If I'm understanding correctly another option would be to write XML for each legacy bean that would substitute for the annotations.  Since posting I learned I could use Eclipse and JAXB default implementation to generate Schema files for all the legacy beans.  I'm guessing this would get us 90% of the way to the XSDs we want, and we'd just have to add a little extra stuff to the XSDs for things like custom package names and stopping circular refs.  I wish I could avoid the assembling phase but not sure if thats possible without adding client dependency on legacy beans.